# What could cause deny,allow directive to be ignored in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I cannot get allow and deny directives to work from an htaccess file within any directory in my web root.  I am at a loss as to where I should look to configure this.  I have checked the obvious (authz modules are loaded, allow overrides is set to all)  Any ideas?  Here are my configuration details.

I have an Apache 2.2 server running on RHEL.  Within this server I have an IP based VirtualHost that is configured like where myipaddr and myserver are the actual IP address and host name respectively:

```
<VirtualHost    myipaddr:80>
ServerName      myserver
TransferLog     /var/log/httpd/myserver.access
LogFormat       loadbalanced
ErrorLog        /var/log/httpd/myserver.error

DocumentRoot    /var/www/myserver
<Directory /var/www/myserver>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried more complex directives but even a simple .htaccess file that should deny everything has no effect.

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Comment: Did you make sure you restarted Apache after you made all the changes?

Comment: Yes, I did a restart and not just a reload.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the was a configuration file in /etc/httpd/conf.d that I did not realize was getting loaded and it was trumping the denies and allows within specific directories.

```
   <Location />
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      <LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE>
         Deny from all
      </LimitExcept>
   </Location>
```